# Decrease the text size or button size in notifications area

Tags: settings, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-6, fonts, k9-mail

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android Lollipop. As you see in this picture, there is a button "Reply" (Svara) and then a button "Mark as read" (Markera som L...). But the buttons are so large, it causes the third button "Delete" to be hidden to the right, e.g. after the "..." shown.

[image]

How can I decrease the text/button size in the notification area?

Comment: Don't think it possible without root

Comment: And rooting is illegal in my country of residence due to strict "DMCA" type of laws. However, it was possible on my phone to grant certain (I don't know which, but language settings was possible to grant) system permissions via adb (pm grant ....) so such a solution with adb is acceptable too, if I in some way can permanently reduce the font size in notifications. It doesn't matter if the text gets small, I have good eyes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking most likely cannot be done (at least easily, anyway). Those buttons might be controlled by the system UI or the app creating the notification. You can try your `System Settings` > `Display` > `Font size`, but this will alter the font size on everything.

Alternatively, here's an easier fix- **tilt the phone to landscape to widen the notification window**.

After installing the [K-9 App for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=en), I find that my notifications on my Galaxy S3 are a bit different. Can you confirm that you have the `Delete` button set to show in the settings?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Font size is smallest already. Tilting the phone wont work in launcher. Only when inside some app. Should try and see if it helps to download a extremely small custom font, but I don't think it will affect notifications.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen Hmm... tilting the phone should work if you tap that Screen Rotation icon in your Quick Settings. But I know what you mean- I have my launcher set to "force portrait" too.

Comment: I tried to enable screen rotation. Im not dumb :-) But forcing potrait is not a option, I need something that I can act on when I get the notification, and then go back again.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen - Sorry, I didn't mean to imply a lack of intelligence. I don't use K-9 but just installed to test how the notifications look on my Galaxy S3 (took me a while as K-9 wouldn't accept three of the four email accounts I tried- weird). I edited the answer above.

Comment: yes, "Delete" button is enabled. However, I can clearly see that your phone is not Lollipop. This issue only exist on lollipop.